# How to return JMS answer in REST

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jms

So I am writing REST Service in which I want to return JMS answer from queue.
Everythink looks like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class UserService {

   @Autowired
   JMSProducer jmsproducer;

   @RequestMapping(value="/users", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public String getUsers(){
      return jmsproducer.send();
   }    
}
```

Method send() send message to queue to BACKEND ( backend have connection to DataBase ) then backend send in queue message all users to my rest and then my JMSProducer class with method onMessage from MessageListener receive sended message. (using MessageProducer's and MessageConsumer's)

Question is: How can i receive this all users from queue on this method getUsers because onMessage function is void type.

Please help me, i don't have any idea how to do that in a good way.
I am using ActiveMQ.

Comment: After you call send, your REST method will need to block execution until your JMS producer has received the "all users" message from your backend. One possible way to implement this would be to have the onMessage method store the data in a member variable that can be accessed by your REST method. In the REST method, you would need to loop and poll that variable until it has a value, which you can then return to the caller.

Comment: You want me to create while loop whitch will be checking that  variable has a value? I think its bad idea when i will have for example 10 rest methods...

Comment: Instead of writing your own look at Spring Integration or try the `JmsTemplate.sendAndReceive` methods. How to de request/response with JMS is documented enough on the internet.

Comment: @M.Deinum
Thank you for advice, its working like I want it :)